# An irreducible polynomial question

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\mathbb F$ be a field and $f(x)$ an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb F[x]$. Let $c$ be an element of $\mathbb F[x]/(f)$. Show that there exists $g \in \mathbb F[x]$, $g\neq 0$, such that $g(c)=0$.

We have to prove that $c$ is algebraic. I don't have any idea how to proceed.

Comment: You want to assume $g \neq 0$ (otherwise it's trivial). Finite field (ring) extensions are always algebraic (integral). We don't even need that $f$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** What can you say about the degree $$\left\lvert \frac{\mathbb F[x]}{\langle f(x) \rangle} : \mathbb F \right\rvert$$

Comment: I think it is $\big| F\big| ^{n-1}$. So $\frac{\mathbb F[x]}{<f(x)>}$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb F$ and thus it is algebraic.

Comment: Is this logic correct?

Comment: @math89, the degree of the extension is $n =$ the degree of $f(x)$. Then your argument is correct.